# Fonts are broken on Mark as Duplicate (Gold Badge) user tooltip message

Tags: bug

Title says it all, it seems like fonts are broken on Tooltip when the question is marked as duplicate by a gold badge user. Screenshot for the same is attached below.

[image]

Or that's intentional :p

> Info : 
>   Windows 7
>   Browser: Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m